# Scala: how do I get the annotations on an expression?

Tags: scala, annotations

In the Scala language specification, §6.14 Annotated Expressions:

> An annotated expression e: @a1 ... @an attaches annotations a1, ..., an to the expression e.

While I can get annotations just fine on classes (and their member values and methods), I can't find a way to get the annotations on an expression at runtime.

Say I have `val x = C(f1 = v1 : @a1, f2 = v2 : @a2)`, how do I get annotations `@a1` and `@a2` from x's fields? (where C is a case class and @aX may be custom annotations)

Comment: You should add some code of what you're doing. How do you get annotations for classes, what have you tried to get them for expressions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using runtime reflection I don't believe you can access any expressions (except for annotation values and default parameter values; there may be something else I am overlooking) at all, and so you can't access any annotations on them.

You need `C` or `C.apply` to be a macro (or use a compiler plugin).

Comment: I suspected as much... Thanks for your reply.